# How to Make Site with multiple Pop-Ups - like http://www.everythingnow.com

Tags: popup

I'm a beginner with only basic css and html knowledge, but want to learn to create a site like http://www.everythingnow.com.

I want the popup windows to be drag-able by users.

Even just being pointed in the right direction would help infinitely. ty!